# mysql optimization UPDATE JOIN performance indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've this query:

```
"explain UPDATE requests R JOIN profile as P ON R.intern_id = P.intern_id OR R.intern_id_decoded = P.intern_id OR R.intern_id_full_decode = P.intern_id SET R.found_id=P.id WHERE R.id >= 28000001 AND R.id <= 28000001+2000000 AND R.found_id is NULL"
1       UPDATE  R       NULL    range   PRIMARY,intern_id_customer_id_batch_num,id_found_id     PRIMARY 4       NULL    3616888 10.00   Using where
1       SIMPLE  P       NULL    ALL     intern_id_dt_snapshot,intern_id NULL    NULL    NULL    179586254       27.10   Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6)
```

That query takes about 40 seconds to execute, it's updating 5000-10000 rows from the set of 2 million rows.

I am currently updating in 2 million row "jobs" to make the join perform faster.
The whole table is 170 million records currently.

The EXPLAIN shows the second part without using an INDEX, I am not sure if that's right or not.
The intern_id fields are varchars, found_id and id are INT

Does the explain output look like it's working performantly ?
I noticed the second line does not use an index, not sure if that's normal.

Comment: I seem to recall MySQL stopping using indexes when you do a range. Try putting the R.found_id IS NULL first.

Comment: No change in output sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this logic using multiple joins:

```
UPDATE requests r LEFT JOIN
       profile p1
       ON r.intern_id = p1.intern_id LEFT JOIN
       profile p2
       ON r.intern_id_decoded = p2.intern_id AND p1.id IS NULL LEFT JOIN
       profile p3
       ON r.intern_id_full_decode = p3.intern_id AND p2.id IS NULL
    SET r.found_id = COALESCE(p1.id, p2.id, p3.id)
    WHERE R.id >= 28000001 AND R.id <= 28000001 + 2000000 AND
          R.found_id is NULL;
```

Databases are very bad at optimizing `OR` in `JOIN` conditions.  It might be better with explicit `JOIN`s.

The `ON` conditions also ensure only the first match.

Comment: I'm playing with that right now and it's considerable faster.
Probably 10-15 times better performance than before.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do 3 chunked-up `UPDATEs` -- one for each of the `ON` conditions.

10K rows to update is excessive; crank it down to perhaps 1K.  That means cranking the chunking down to 200K.  (The speed *might* even be faster.)

```
UPDATE ... ON P.intern_id = R.intern_id          SET ... WHERE ...
UPDATE ... ON P.intern_id = R.intern_id_decoded  SET ... WHERE ...
UPDATE ... ON P.intern_id = R.intern_id_full     SET ... WHERE ...
```

(The range is the same fore each set of 3, thereby helping with caching of R.)

Possibly `INDEX(found_id)` would help, but this is not a given.

See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) for more chunking suggestions, especially the tip on finding 1000 rows *before* starting the operation:

```
SELECT id WHERE id > ... AND found_id IS NULL LIMIT 1000,1;
```

Then using that as the limit instead of the 2-millionth.  A goal here is to even out the number of rows updated.